# great good luck or greatly lucky for using in a sentence

Tags: word-request

I found the usage of ''great good luck'' on ngram.
But I can't found ''greatly lucky''. So, please  advise  me whether I can use  ''greatly lucky'' in my writing.

Comment: "Greatly" is a very formal adverb and would not be used to modify _lucky_ in idiomatic English. Try _"extremely lucky"_ instead (or _"yuuuugely lucky"_ to emulate the diction of the smartest guy in the Western world.)

Answer (score 1):

"Great good luck" is an idiomatic phrase that's rarely used.  "Great" does not modify "good". It's actually just two adjectives, both modifying "luck".  Other examples:

> A large round stone
>
> A ripe red tomato
>
> smooth creamy butter

"Greatly" is an adverb that is not uncommon, but not idiomatically paired with "lucky".  There is no reason for this, it's just not something native English speakers say.  However, as P.E. Dant mentions in his comment, "extremely lucky" and "hugely lucky" can be idiomatic.